# Tranlation of a text message (你好我係喜歡派對 ?)

Tags: translation

Just got a snap from a friend who moved to Shanghai, and she wrote something in Chinese, which I dont have a clue of what it means.

[image: image of text]

Tentative OCR: 你好我係喜歡派對

Comment: "Hi I like partying."

Comment: If you have this much you should consider installing a Chinese-English dictionary in your computer. For MacOSX I provide some links and tools on my profile. For Windows, just search the CSE for "resources" or use the translate.google.com to get a headstart.

Answer (score 2):

It means "Hello,I (do) like parties"